# Python colored output doesn't work except when piping

Tags: python, bash, colors, git-bash, windows-terminal

I'm using Git Bash on Windows inside Windows Terminal and I'm writing a python script which needs to output colored text. As an example, I have the following one-line script named `example.py`:

```py
print('\033[35m\033[K' + 'hello world' + '\033[m\033[K')
```

When I run the command `python example.py`, I expect to see colored output, but instead I get this:

```
←[35m←[Khello world←[m←[K
```

However, if I run `python example.py | cat`, I get the colored output I expect. How weird. I also get nice colored output if I run the script from cmd instead of bash, or if I run the line from the live interpreter (but not if it is a child of bash).

Any ideas? If possible I prefer to solve this without bringing in dependencies like Colorama.

EDIT: I resigned to using Colorama after seeing the replies. All it took to fix it was a call to the aptly named `colorama.just_fix_windows_console()`. Dependency-less solutions still welcome.

EDIT 2: Interestingly, this problem does not occur on my laptop which has what I thought was the exact same setup.

Comment: I believe there are known issues with ANSI escape codes and Git Bash for Windows, see https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/6634

Comment: I _think_ that this is exactly what the [Colorama project](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) is there to solve.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I tried the following basic script,

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
print('\033[35m\033[K' + 'hello world' + '\033[m\033[K')
```

and I got the result which you were likely looking for, namely

[image]

**Since you mentioned [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)**, to get what you wanted, you need to read the section of the bash man page for printf more closely.

The round brackets are used in AWK, C, others.  Bash shows no mention of round brackets in the usage syntax.  However, you need to add a "format" specifier (NOT same as AWK), but per the man page.

Your statement should be reworked to show as this:

```
printf "%b\n" "\033[35m\033[K" "hello world" "\033[m\033[K"
```

OR ... you could just replace the **printf "%b\n"** with simply **echo -e** to get the same result.

Of possible interest, I also created for myself what I call a "Bourne Header" file, in which I defined some preset combinations with variable strings that can be re-used in other scripts by simply source'ing the *.bh file.  I include it here for general usage.

```
#!/bin/sh

##########################################################################################################
### $Id: INCLUDES__TerminalEscape_SGR.bh,v 1.2 2022/09/03 01:57:31 root Exp root $
###
### This includes string variables defined to perform various substitutions for the ANSI Terminal Escape Sequences, i.e. SGR (Select Graphic Rendition subset)
##########################################################################################################

### REFERENCE:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code
###             https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-48/

### "\e" is same as "\033"

style_e()
{
boldON="\e[1m"
boldOFF="\e[0m"

italicON="\e[3m"
italicOFF="\e[0m"

underlineON="\e[4m"
underlineOFF="\e[0m"

blinkON="\e[5m"
blinkOFF="\e[0m"

cyanON="\e[96;1m"
cyanOFF="\e[0m"

cyanDarkON="\e[36;1m"
cyanDarkOFF="\e[0m"

greenON="\e[92;1m"
greenOFF="\e[0m"

yellowON="\e[93;1m"
yellowOFF="\e[0m"

redON="\e[91;1m"
redOFF="\e[0m"

orangeON="\e[33;1m"
orangeOFF="\e[0m"

blueON="\e[94;1m"
blueOFF="\e[0m"

blueSteelON="\e[34;1m"
blueSteelOFF="\e[0m"

darkBlueON="\e[38;2;95;95;255m"
darkBlueOFF="\e[0m"

magentaON="\e[95;1m"
magentaOFF="\e[0m"
}

style_o()
{
boldON="\033[1m"
boldOFF="\033[0m"

italicON="\033[3m"
italicOFF="\033[0m"

underlineON="\033[4m"
underlineOFF="\033[0m"

blinkON="\033[5m"
blinkOFF="\033[0m"

cyanON="\033[96;1m"
cyanOFF="\033[0m"

cyanDarkON="\033[36;1m"
cyanDarkOFF="\033[0m"

greenON="\033[92;1m"
greenOFF="\033[0m"

yellowON="\033[93;1m"
yellowOFF="\033[0m"

redON="\033[91;1m"
redOFF="\033[0m"

orangeON="\033[33;1m"
orangeOFF="\033[0m"

blueON="\033[94;1m"
blueOFF="\033[0m"

blueSteelON="\033[34;1m"
blueSteelOFF="\033[0m"

darkBlueON="\033[38;2;95;95;255m"
darkBlueOFF="\033[0m"

magentaON="\033[95;1m"
magentaOFF="\033[0m"
}

#style_e
style_o

##########################################################################################################
### Usage Examples:
##########################################################################################################

#   echo "\t RSYNC process is ${redON}not${redOFF} running (or has already ${greenON}terminated${greenOFF}).\n"
#   echo "\t ${PID} is ${cyanON}${italicON}${descr}${italicOFF}${cyanOFF} process ..."
#   echo "\t ${PID} is ${yellowON}${descr}${yellowOFF} process ..."
#   echo "\n\n\t RSYNC process (# ${pid}) has ${greenON}completed${greenOFF}.\n"

##########################################################################################################
### Example of scenario where escape codes are hard-coded; \e was not accepted by awk
##########################################################################################################

#   echo "\n\t ${testor}\n" | sed 's+--+\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t--+g' | awk '{
#       rLOC=index($0,"rsync") ;
#       if( rLOC != 0 ){
#           sBeg=sprintf("%s", substr($0,1,rLOC-1) ) ;
#           sEnd=sprintf("%s", substr($0,rLOC+5) ) ;
#           sMid="\033[91;1mrsync\033[0m" ;
#           printf("%s%s%s\n", sBeg, sMid, sEnd) ;
#       }else{
#           print $0 ;
#       } ;
#   }'

##########################################################################################################
    echo "\n\t Imported LIBRARY:  INCLUDES__TerminalEscape_SGR.bh ..."
##########################################################################################################
```

You could likewise define your own set of preset escape sequences as formatting variables.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking to write the code in bash, I'm using python. Bash is only the shell from which I ran the python script. I just thought it was relevant.